# Connection to rest web service

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I have spring MVC rest application and front application that consumes services from rest  application. If not connected user try to use service from rest app then connection web service will be invoked.
Connection webservice use spring saml to connect user to Active directory.
How can I propagate the connection to the front application?

Comment: Please provide some code?

Comment: I have no idea about the mechanism to use. My question is about what I have to use for that.

Comment: I resolve the problem by using spring oauth2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement that I use Spring oauth2. My Rest Api is the resource server and the client Api is oauth2 client. Hope that will help